# What is this "the?"

Tags: articles, definite-article

> This novel is of **the** poorest.
>   His clothes verge on **the** shabby.

What is this "the"? 
It doesn't look the same as "the supernatural" meaing "supernatural phenomena..." etc

Comment: A hint: to transition to a new line, use a double-space (press the long white button twice).

Answer (score 1):

"of the poorest" is an idiomatic formula meaning "of the poorest kind". There are variants of this type of formula. Compare

- to live life to the fullest.
- I tried my hardest.